# Why computational problems like this that do with I/O or access shared data need more than Ncpu threads yield optimal throughput?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Java Concurrency in Practice:

> For computational problems like this that do no I/O and access no shared data, N<sub>cpu</sub> or N<sub>cpu</sub>+ 1 threads yield optimal throughput; more threads do not help, and may in fact degrade performance as the threads compete for CPU and memory resources.

Why computational problems like this that do with I/O or access shared data need more than Ncpu threads yield optimal throughput?

My understanding:

> I/O operation will be blocked.Shared data will be synchronized by locking,other threads also will be blocked wait for shared data lock.If just N<sub>cpu</sub> threads,threads will be blocked,cpu will remains idle, which lead to cpu unused.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why computational problems like this that do with I/O or access shared data need more than Ncpu threads yield optimal throughput?

They don't necessarily<sup>1</sup> *need* more threads.

What the quoted is implying is that a problem with significant I/O or significant lock contention may<sup>2</sup> *benefit* from more threads than CPUs.  Adding more threads may increase *throughput*.  If a thread blocks on I/O or a lock, the scheduler will try to reassign the CPU to another thread.  So if there are more threads than CPUs, it is *more likely* that there will be a thread waiting to be run.

---

<sup>1 - For example, if there isn't any actual work to be done, adding threads makes no difference.  Also, you may not want the application to use all available resources.  "Optimal throughput" may need to be considered at a larger scale than a single Java application.

2 - We can't say that it **will** benefit.  For example, if the system is already I/O saturated, then adding an extra thread that is going just generate more I/O traffic is won't help.  A similar argument may apply with lock contention.</sup>

Comment: When just Ncpu threads,They are all blocked blocked by significant I/O or significant lock contention. The scheduler will can't reassign the CPU to another thread(No extra threads).So is my view  correct?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you are saying ..... Yes.

Comment: Is my English too bad, so don't you understand what I said?

Comment: I said I think I understand.  But I'm not sure that I understand.